# 150M records order by name

Tags: sql, rdbms, large-data

I have a dataset of around 150 million records that's generated daily it contains:
`member_id`, `member_name`, `member_name_first_letter`

I need to get the list ordered by `member_name asc`

I have try with MySQL if i break down by first letter of member_name and run the query for everyone once (around 40 different: A-Z, digits, special chars) I'm able to fill a table in around total 40 min, without breakdown to frist later it tkaes hours. for the test i'm using only 13 million records.
Anyway I need to get them much faster (target: 1-2 min).

How I can do that? Can MongoDB help?

Comment: Are you breaking down your *query* by first-letter, or breaking out the records into separate tables?

Comment: I'm actually breaking down by first letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use InnoDB, and make member_name the primary key of the table, it will always be ordered by that column implicitly, so you can `SELECT ... FROM members` with no order-by clause.  InnoDB tables are actually a *clustered index*.

---

Re your comment:  You could also define a *compound primary key* and the table would be in member_name order if member_name is the first column in the primary key.

Comment: key can be not primary try regular KEY

Answer (score 0):

Mongo is not an option, try to use index on member_name,
other solutions is to order and data and split to several tables or create index for member_name field using external tools

Comment: MongoDB is an *option*, it's just not going to do much different.

Comment: we have try with/without index there is no difference, but what you mean with external tools? the split to several tables would complicate the handling and we hope to be able to find a solution without this.

Comment: did you used `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename` after creating index? it will take time but can speed up requests. external tools meant create external ordered index for member_name field, mongo possibly can help here, but this way needs additional programming and integration, maybe efforts proportionately to table splitting

Answer (score 0):

Extending Bill Karwin's idea, if you can add a new column while acquiring the data, you can generate a unique primary key by appending a timestamp to the name, separated by a space to avoid any weird concatenation problems (well its unlikely anyone's name would be numeric, but still).

Comment: the member_name can have every kind of chars it's like a nickname. I'm now testing how it perform if i add on generating UUID to end of name and select after LEFT, 36. result: 10 minutes - ok that's 4 time faster for my 13m test set!